# Error/warnings list in IDEA

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

Does Idea have a error/problems list like in eclipse?
I mean something like this: [image]

Comment: did you type Public instead of public? show your codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alt+0 to bring up the Messages tab

Or click on View -> Tool Windows -> Messages

If you click on Build -> Make Project or just Ctrl+F9 this should automatically bring it up if you have any errors.

Comment: I don't have this option. I use Idea Ultimate 2016.1

Comment: Try  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html#run_app for further information

Comment: When I did build this option was appeared